# How to handle exception when changing the Autocommit mode in a commit / rollback method?

Tags: java, exception, transactions

I am writing 1 method to commit a transaction. If an error occur I want to throw an exception `CommitTransactionException`. So this will be the method:

```
public void commitTransaction() throws CommitTransactionException {
    try {
        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw new CommitTransactionException(sqle);
    }
}
```

Now whether commit is successful or fail, I also want to set the Autocommit mode to true. So I was thinking about adding a finally block in this method where I will set the Autocommit mode to true:

```
finally {
   connection.setAutoCommit(true);
}
```

But the problem is `setAutoCommit` method can throw an exception `SQLException` so how to handle that exception?

One way I was thinking was to translate the exception `SQLException` from `setAutoCommit` method to `CommitTransactionException` exception as well:

```
public void commitTransaction() throws CommitTransactionException {
    try {
        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw new CommitTransactionException(sqle);
    } finally {
        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw new CommitTransactionException(sqle);
        }
    }
}
```

But then caller will think that Commit failed even when Commit was successful and setting Autocommit mode failed.

How this type of stuff is usually handled in Java?

Comment: check this one out - [Apache.Commons DbUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.html)

Comment: so basically just eat the `SQLException` from `setAutoCommit` method in my `commitTransaction()` method and dont let caller know about it?

Comment: Do you expect the caller to be able to recover from `setAutoCommit` failing? If yes, either propagate the `SQLException` (add it to your method's `throws`) or handle it the same way as the commit exception: add a `SetAutoCommitException`. If no, either keep what you have, or wrap it in any `RuntimeException`.